# Excel: How to count every n cell, whether the value is above or below 0

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have used `{=STDEV.P(IF(MOD(ROW($E$1:$E$1000),4)=1,IF($E$1:$E$1000<>"",$E$1:$E$1000)))}` to calculate sigma of every 4th cell in column `E:E` aggregated, same goes for the mean and sum. Now, I find myself with a problem as `{=countif(IF(MOD(ROW($E$1:$E$1000),4)=1,IF($E$1:$E$1000<>"",$E$1:$E$1000)),">0")}` does not work. Can you please advise how to reformat the formula so it can count number of positive values every x (4th) number of cells?

Thx

Comment: **unclear** do you want the **count** the cells or **sum** the cells, or calculate the **standard deviation** of the cells??

Comment: in the title I wrote "count"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe that sum(if(...)) will work better with array formulas. I experienced similar issues in array formulas with different functions. Also since sum function disregards "" you don need to use $E$1:$E$1000<>"" condition. I believe that following array formula will do the trick for your case. `{=SUM(IF((MOD(ROW($E$1:$E$1000),4)=1)*($E$1:$E$1000>0),1,0))}` .